# Stop button in LabVIEW cannot be pressed during while loop execution inside an event structure

Tags: labview

I am currently working on a LabVIEW project and have found myself stuck on how to make a while loop exit when I press the abort (stop) button. For a simple while loop I understand how to do this - but the problem is that this while loop is nested inside of an event structure and I'm guessing that the button cannot be pressed while the loop is executing. Attached here is a picture of part of my code (that contains this specific event case which is causing me problems): [image: Stop Button Inside While loop] To spend a little more time explaining what the problem is - I think the code is doing what I want it to do (namely output a set of commands in a repeated cycle with a wait timer) but I cannot stop the code mid cycle (pressing the abort button with my mouse does nothing - as in the button doesn't show it being pressed and the indicator shows no change, I also can't use any other functionality of my program during the cycle which I'm assuming is related). And I do not want to stop the LabVIEW program from running entirely - just the code inside the while loop pictured above. This is what the front panel is configured too for completeness: [image: front panel for stop button]

Essentially what I want to happen is the while loop to execute when I press DWG and in the middle of the cycle be able to abort it. Sorry if my code seems a little messy. Additionally, I've tried the same code with a for loop originally (via a conditional terminal so it could stop early) and that didn't work either. Thanks for any help I appreciate it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that inside the event structure, by default the UI is frozen so no UI actions (keyboard/mouse/etc) are processed until you exit that frame.

**Option 1.** You *can* right click the Event Structure and select "Edit events handled by this case" dialog and then uncheck the "Lock panel" checkbox -- that will allow the UI to be live while you are in that frame. I do not recommend this solution generally unless you have an extremely simple user interface because it leads to the user being able to change controls without the events behind those controls being processed (not a good UI experience for users). But if the UI is simple enough, that works.

**Option 2.** You can create a user event that is the code you want inside your While Loop. When the Deg Wait Go button is pressed, use the "Generate User Event" node to trigger that event. Do the same thing in the user event case so that the event re-triggers itself if and only if the Abort button has not been pressed.

**Option 3.** Create a separate loop OUTSIDE your UI loop that does your processing with some sort of command queue running between the UI loop and  that other loop. The other loop moves into various states at the request of the UI loop... it's the one that does nothing until it receives a "go" message and then keeps looping until it receives a "stop" message. You can Google "queued message handler" for extensive details of this solution. This is the most common solution for complex UI requirements, especially useful for separating concerns of the UI code from the execution code.

Comment: Thanks for you're informative reply! Option 1 worked perfectly but I was wondering if you could elaborate a little more on the downsides of using it versus Option 3 which seems to be the industry standard (I'm unfamiliar with Queues but I did watch some videos on them). Thanks again!

Comment: If the UI isn’t frozen while events are handled, you can have users click a button then click on other buttons that are supposed to be grayed out after the first button press... that’s just one example of the odd UI states that become possible.